# Flask Debug Console when using dash plotly

Tags: plotly-dash

I would like to use the Flask browser debugger when an error happens *outside* a callback (for example a user-defined route) in a dash application. Unfortunately, the console icon doesn't appear in the traceback (see screenshot). This problem seems to appear once connecting the flask server with `dash.Dash(server=server)`.

Below find the minimal example I am using. The error is raised when navigating to http://localhost/abc.

Any ideas?

[image]

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from flask import Flask

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']


server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(server=server, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


@server.route('/abc')
def main():
    raise Exception()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='my-id', value='initial value', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='my-div')
])


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'You\'ve entered "{}"'.format(input_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```